# Can we get a Monarch tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I just created [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1342606/monarch-if-statement-with-date). I tagged it excel, because the formulas are roughly analogous.

Answer (score 1):

I added the tag and made your question more readable. Not sure if it is necessary to write an answer but you might want to explain, what you mean by but then it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Its not compulsory, but really appreciated if tag wiki related things are filled up. _ guess [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarch_(software)) is monarch?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I fairly new to being active on this site, so I guess this might sound like a stupid question, what do you mean by "if tag wiki related things are filled up"?  I assume you mean the description that pops up with the tag? Completely didn't consider that, so sorry! Good thing you mention it, next time I'll do a better job! I'll have to read up on how to do it an how to do a proper job on it. Also yes, you have the correct link, that is monarch.

Comment: Oh. Lots of folks forget. Some folks get lazy and just copy over a bunch of stuff off the internet. Paraphrasing is the best idea here

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ok, thanks so much. I'll correct that (although not today, I'll have a client meeting I need to take care of)

Comment: Sorry about that - yes Journeyman Geek, that's Monarch. It's software that can be used with a variety of formats, I use it with excel.  So I was basically asking for a tag to be created so that it'd be easier to look for Monarch related items in the future (if there are any!).

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles I added general information on the tag, please feel free to fill in more details or correct any mistakes I made.